# Rename column names through the loop (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table:

I have the table like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5], [20, 15, 10, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['asd', 'bsd', 'tsd', 'pzd'])
df
```

| asd | bsd | tsd | pzd | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |

I want to rename all my column names with the pattern like this `'param'+ (index_column +1)` through the loop

Desired output:

| param1 | param2 | param3 | param4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |
| 20 | 15 | 10 | 5 | ... |

Thanks

Comment: why did you not just do this? : `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['param1','param2','param3','param4'])`

Comment: @Theshape because a lot of columns

Comment: o i see @Smasell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use any loop.
Just create a new list of column names, in a list comprehension
and set it as new column names:

```
df.columns = [ 'param' + str(i + 1) for i in range(len(df.columns)) ]
```